# magento 2 need to customize after product save

Tags: magento2

i need to add data in my custom table if product saved successfully ,if i use observer it will work only for admin , i need every if product saved triggered need to add data in my custom table.
how to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Your code work for frontend too. but only If you used "**catalog_product_save_after**" event instead of **controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after**

just please put your events.xml globally instead of adminhtml as below

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml
```

Comment: Thanks,@Gohil Rajesh is this working while order placed successfully and product import process as well?

Comment: No..not on both section...On order place product save event will never call...its minus qty only not saving whole product...you can add your login on order place after event..and import will also not call that event